# Is there a way to select the 1st Unity search result with 1 keystroke?

Tags: unity, 12.04, shortcut-keys, unity-dash

In this example I'd like to select Ubuntu Software Center.

I know you can press down arrow twice to select, but the extra key seems unnecessary. In old versions of Ubuntu I remember using tab, but that no longer seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply pressing the return key will select the first result once a search has been entered, but selecting the second result onwards has to be done by pressing the down arrow twice and then moving across to the correct choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can just press Enter and it will launch the first search result :)